# Ambiguous column names while querying mySQL using Metabase

Tags: metabase

I'm Getting

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'pid' in on clause is ambiguous
```

I have two tables having columns with the same name (pid).

Is there a way to make metabase use `tablename.columnname` format to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in v0.30.1

Comment: I just got the same error with v0.30.2, and upgraded to v.0.30.4 which fixed it. i think it was fixed in v0.30.3.